# Javascript Serial Number CoderByte problem

Tags: javascript

I'm currently solving a problem at CoderByte. Here's the scenario.

Have the function SerialNumber(str) take the str parameter being passed and determine if it is a valid serial number with the following constraints:

1. It needs to contain three sets each with three digits (1 through 9) separated by a period.
2. The first set of digits must add up to an even number.
3. The second set of digits must add up to an odd number.
4. The last digit in each set must be larger than the two previous digits in the same set.

If all the above constraints are met within the string, the your program should return the string true, otherwise your program should return the string false. For example: if str is "224.315.218" then your program should return "true".

```
Examples
Input: "11.124.667"
Output: false

Input: "114.568.112"
Output: true
```

Here's my JS code for this problem.

```js
function SerialNumber(str) { 

  // code goes here
  if(str.length < 11) {
    return "false";
  }

  for (let x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
    if(str[x] === '0') {
      return "false";
    }
  }
  
  const first = str[0] + str[1] + str[2];
  const second = str[4] + str[5]+ str[6];

  if (first % 2 !== 0 || second % 2 === 0) {
    return "false";
  }

  if (str[2] < str[1] || str[2] < str[0] || str[6] < str[5] || str[6] < str[4] || str[10] < str[8] || str[10] < str[9]) {
    return "false";
  } else {
    return "true";
  }
}

console.log("11.124.667 : " + SerialNumber("11.124.667"));
console.log("114.568.112 : " + SerialNumber("114.568.112"));
```

When I input `"11.124.667"`, it will return to `false` (which is correct). And when I input `"114.568.112"`, it will also return to `false` (which is not correct). Any tips on how can I obtain this? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I recommend you to log something on each step to see which condition cause your incorrect output, with 6 different ways to output false, it's hard to see the problem

Comment: you mean, I had to make 6 if statement each?

Comment: Well `first % 2 !== 0` returns true at your given example, so no wonder while it shows "false".

Comment: @Reporter so I need to separate those 2 conditions?

Comment: Edit: `second % 2 === 0`was true because 568 is even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and the problem comes from the third `return false` for the 2nd example, when you set `second`, you concatenate strings instead of adding numbers, thus `%2` is always equal to `0` since
I added `console.log` before each `return false` to see which condition failed.
Here's the fixed code in which I added `parseInt` for `first` and `second`

```js
function SerialNumber(str) {

    if (str.length < 11) {
        console.log("first")
        return "false";
    }

    for (let x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
        if (str[x] === '0') {
            console.log("second")
            return "false";
        }
    }

    const first = parseInt(str[0]) + parseInt(str[1]) + parseInt(str[2]);
    const second = parseInt(str[4]) + parseInt(str[5]) + parseInt(str[6]);

    if (first % 2 !== 0 || second % 2 === 0) {
        console.log("third")
        return "false";
    }

    if (str[2] < str[1] || str[2] < str[0] || str[6] < str[5] || str[6] < str[4] || str[10] < str[8] || str[10] < str[9]) {
        console.log("fourth")
        return "false";
    } else {
        return "true";
    }
}

console.log("11.124.667 : " + SerialNumber("11.124.667"));
console.log("114.568.112 : " + SerialNumber("114.568.112"))
```

Comment: I got it. The `parseInt` solved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string StringChallenge(string str) {

    string s = "";
    int arr[3];
    int i=0;
    int j = 2;
    str = str + "x";
    int k=0;
    int n;
    while(i<=8 && k<3)
    {
        if(str[3] == '.' && str[7] == '.')
        {
            s = str.substr(i,3);
            n = stoi(s);
            arr[k] = n;
            i = i+4;
            k++;
            
        }
        else{
            return "false";
        }   
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    
    if(arr[0]>99 && arr[0]%2 == 0 && arr[0]%10 < arr[0]/10)
   {
     if(arr[1]>99 && arr[1]%2 == 1 && arr[1]%10 < arr[1]/10)
     {
       if(arr[2]>99 && arr[2]%10 < arr[2]/10 )
       {
         return "true";
       }
     }
   }
   return "false";
 }
 

int main(void) { 
   
  // keep this function call here
    string s = "122.122.667";
  cout << StringChallenge(s);
  return 0;
    
}
```

**I did this in 1 hour 15 minutes which means i could solve this question only sadly**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in **kotlin**

```
 fun SerialNumber(str: String): String {
val series= str.split('.').toList()
if(series.size!=3){
 return "false"
}
for(pair in series){
 if(pair.length !=3){
   return "false"   
 }
}

val digits= series.get(0).map{it.toString().toInt() }
if(digits.sum()% 2 !=0){
   return "false"       
}
 
val digitsTwo= series.get(1).map{it.toString().toInt() }
if(digitsTwo.sum()% 2 !=1){
   return "false"       
}

for(s in series){
  var sets= s.map{it.toString().toInt()}
 if(!(sets.last()>sets.take(2).maxOrNull()?:0)){
   return "false"   
 }
}



return "true"

}

fun main() {
  println(SerialNumber(readLine()))
}
```